# Downloading Oracle 10g database for windows 7 64-bit

Tags: windows, oracle, oracle10g

I was searching for link to download Oracle 10g R2 database for windows 7 64-bit because this version of database is not available on the Oracle official website.

Thanks a lot

Comment: Oracle 10g is no longer supported and you can only get it if you pay Oracle a **lot** of money for an extended support contract. You need to ask your Oracle sales representative to get you a copy.

Comment: Perhaps Oracle 10g R2 does not work with Windows 7, according [Oracle Database Software Requirements](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/install.102/b15681/reqs.htm#CHDHGGFE) it is not supported. Anyway, why do you like to install an outdated Oracle version - even 11g is already end of life. Another topic, if your client application has the latest client version installed then most likely it won't be able to connect to the database.